# Meaning of those two expressions with cat?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cat

This is first time that I am using Linux, and I need to understand some concepts about two commands. I would be happy if you could explain the process one by one.

What does this command do?

```
cat ../test
```

And what does this command do?

```
cat /etc/shadow 2>&1 | wc -l
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

"../" is the parent directory.
So "cat ../test" means "print the 'test' file located in parent directory to standard output."

Second question:
All Linux (and Unix) processes have 3 standard files.
File 0 is input (stdin).
File 1 is normal output (stdout).
File 2 is error output (stderr).
2&>1 means "transfer error output into standard output".
The pipe | means "transfer output to the input of another program"
And the whole line means "count and display number of lines in /etc/shadow  (including error messages if any).

Answer (score 1):

You probably know what the `cat` command does. The `man` page states:

> cat - concatenate files and print on the standard output

`../` means the parent directory of your current working directory. So, if there is a file called `test` at that location the `cat` command will print it for you on the terminal.

In the second example, the content of `/etc/shadow` (if you have access to), will be `piped` to `wc` command.

> wc - print newline, word, and byte counts for each file

> -l, --lines:               print the newline counts

This will print the number of lines in `/etc/shadow` on the terminal (only the number of lines, not the content). The `2>&1` notation redirects file descriptor 2 (standard error) to file descriptor 1 (standard output).